# Returning queryset that uses a foreign key of a foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-viewsets

It sounds simple enough: get all the Users for a specific Company. But it is complicated by a few things:

- The User model is extended
- The model that extends it contains a UUID that uniquely identifies the user throughout various system integrations
- This UUID is what is used in the company relationship.

So the relationship is `user_to_company__user_uuid` -> `user_extended__user_id` -> `auth_user`. That's what I'd like to return is the User model.

What I have:

```
# url
/api/user_to_company/?company_uuid=0450469d-cbb1-4374-a16f-dd72ce15cf67
```

```
# views.py
class UserToCompanyViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                           mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                           viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    filter_backends = [StrictDjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = [
        'id',
        'user_uuid',
        'company_uuid'
    ]
    permission_classes = [CompanyPermissions]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET['company_uuid']:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(
                user_to_company__company_uuid=self.request.GET['company_uuid'])
        return queryset

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.GET['company_uuid']:
            serializer_class = UserSerializer
        return serializer_class
```

```
# serializers.py

class UserToCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserToCompany
        fields = '__all__'


class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserExtended
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
# models.py

class UserExtended(models.Model):

    user_id = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user_id')
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_extended'

class UserToCompany(models.Model):
    user_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
        UserExtended, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user_uuid', related_name='user_to_company')
    company_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
        Companies, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='company_uuid', related_name='user_to_company')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_to_company'
        unique_together = [['user_uuid', 'company_uuid']]
```

Understandably, in this setup `User.object.filter(user_to_company__company_uuid=self.reqest.GET['company_uuid']` doesn't make sense and it returns `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user_to_company' into field`--There isn't a relationship between User and UserToCompany directly, but there is between User -> UserExtended -> UserToCompany

I could like do this by using `UserExtended.object.filter()`, but that returns an object like :

```
[
  {
    "user_extended_stuff_1": "stuff",
    "user_extended_stuff_2": "more stuff",
    "auth_user": {
      "auth_user_stuff_1": "stuff",
      "auth_user_stuff_2": "more stuff"
    }
  }
]
```

But I need an object like:

```
[
  {
    "auth_user_stuff_1": "stuff",
    "auth_user_stuff_2": "more stuff",
    "user_extended": {
      "user_extended_stuff_1": "stuff",
      "user_extended_stuff_2": "more stuff"
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a way to implement "foreign key of a foreign key" lookup?

I think a work around would get the list of users and then do something like `User.objects.filter(user_ext__user_uuid__in=[querset])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, your endpoint and view are a little bit strange. Probably because you are thinking of using a intermediate model as ViewSet.

Instead what makes more sense is to have a `CompaniesViewSet` with an [extra action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) where you can list all users for a given company. Also, you can access `User` and `UserExtended` in both ways using [relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships):

views.py:

```py
class CompaniesViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                        viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    
    queryset = Companies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompaniesSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def users(self, request):
        pk = request.GET.get('company_uuid', None)
        if pk:
            try:
                instance  = self.get_queryset().get(pk=pk)
                # I Would also change this related name
                qs = instance.user_to_company.all()

                user_list = []
                for obj in qs:
                    # Odd way to access because of your models fields.
                    serializer = UserSerializer(obj.user_uuid.user_id)
                    user_list.append(serializer.data)

                return Response(user_list)
            except ValidationError:
                return Response(
                    {'msg': 'Object with does not exist'}, 
                    status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
                )
        else:
            return Response(
                {'msg': 'missing query string param'}, 
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

serializers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms import model_to_dict

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_extended = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'user_extended']

    def get_user_extended(self, instance):
        # Another odd way to access because of model name
        return model_to_dict(instance.userextended)

class CompaniesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Companies
        fields = '__all__'
```

So, if you register the following:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'companies', views.CompaniesViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

endpoint:

```
/api/companies/users/?company_uuid=0450469d-cbb1-4374-a16f-dd72ce15cf67
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `User` object, you could do something like:

```py
ext_user = UserExtended.objects.get(uuid=self.request.GET['user_uuid'])
auth_user = User.objects.get(id=ext_user.user_id)
```

Then to get the serialized format mentioned, create a `AuthUserSerizalizer` that matches the format,

```py
class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    auth_user_stuff_1 = serializers.Field(...)
    auth_user_stuff_2 = serializers.Field(...)
    user_extended = UserExtendedSerializer()
```

and pass your data to the serializer:

```py
AuthUserSerializer(
    data={
        'auth_user_stuff_1': auth_user.auth_user_stuff_1, 
        'auth_user_stuff_2': auth_user.auth_user_stuff_2, 
        'user_extended': ext_user
    }
)
```